# ExceptionInInitializerError "Parameter specified as non-null is null" with abstract class

Tags: kotlin, lazy-initialization

I need to calculate the `hash` of hard-coded images.

```
abstract class ImageData {
    protected abstract val master: List<String>
    val data: Iterable<HexString> = master.map { s -> hex(s) }
    val hash: Int by lazy {
        master.fold(0) { hash, s ->
            31 * hash + s.hashCode()
        }
    }
}
```

Example image.

```
object FooImageData : ImageData() {
    override val master = listOf(
        "424d3684030000000000..."
        // ...
    )
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ....updateGraphics(Graphics.kt:162)
...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter $this$collectionSizeOrDefault
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt__IterablesKt.collectionSizeOrDefault(Iterables.kt)
    at ....ImageData.<init>(ImageData.kt:17)
    at ....FooImageData.<init>(FooImageData.kt:3)
    at ....FooImageData.<clinit>(FooImageData.kt:3)
    at ....updateGraphics(Graphics.kt:162)
```

at `....updateGraphics(Graphics.kt:162)` is:

```
private suspend fun updateGraphics(...) {
    val hash = (FooImageData.hash * 31 + BarImageData.hash)
```

Removing the `lazy` does not remove the problem.

All research suggests the ordering of the parameters can be an issue but that seems to be not the case here - or is it?

Using:

```
abstract class ImageData {
    abstract val master: List<String>
    // Yes I know the `get()` is unnecessary but for some weird reason that causes `hash` to crash.
    val data: Iterable<HexString> get() = master.map { s -> hex(s) }
    val hash: Int by lazy {
        master.fold(0) { hash, s ->
            31 * hash + s.hashCode()
        }
    }
}
```

seems to solve the problem - no idea why.

Kotlin version `Latest stable (1.3)`

Target JVM version: `1.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key difference is `get()` on the `data` property, in conjunction with the fact that `master` is abstract. When this base class is constructed (which is *before* the subclass is created, since the subclass's constructor has to call the superclass's constructor before anything else), the base class initialises all its members. Your original code had this line:

```
val data: Iterable<HexString> = master.map { s -> hex(s) }
```

This gets the value of master which, at this point, is null, as the concrete subclass hasn't been created yet so can't yet override the property.

In your updated snippet, you have this:

```
val data: Iterable<HexString> get() = master.map { s -> hex(s) }
```

The `data` property now doesn't need to be initialized (using the value of `master`) during initialisation of the abstract base class. Instead, when the `data` property is called at runtime, the `get` function will be executed. By that time the concrete subclass has been constructed and can provide a proper value for `master`.

There's more detail on this in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order), where it says:

> When designing a base class, you should therefore avoid using open
>   members in the constructors, property initializers, and init blocks.

(The `master` property is `abstract`, which means it's `open`.)

Comment: Interesting ... but wouldn't that problem happen at construction time when `data` is initialised? Here the exception happens at run time when `hash` is requested.

Comment: Really?  Interesting.  I just tried your original code and am getting the exception as soon as `FooImageData` is used, on this line in my test code: `val x = FooImageData` (i.e. before I call `hash`). Can you share full code that shows it erroring only when `hash` is called?

Comment: In fact, I think the stack trace of your error shows that it's happening during construction for you too: `at ....FooImageData.<init>(FooImageData.kt:3)` (notice the `init` function here, i.e. during the initialisation of `FooImageData`).

Comment: Oh I see - it's creating the object last-minute.